# How to fix 'Cannot convert Array to Object[][]' error in Google Apps Script

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to get a list of all groups and all members of a group to be posted to a spreadsheet titled 'allGroups'. However, whenever I try to print the Array to the sheet I'm getting the error that says I can't convert the Array to an Object.

I've tried setting the array to be different sizes, changing the range so that it's more specific, and changing the code so that the group name is posted first (clearing the Array) and then moving from there but it hasn't worked.

```
function listAllGroupsAndMembers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var groupPageToken, groupPage;
  var listArray = [];
  var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allGroups') || ss.insertSheet('allGroups', 1);
  outputSheet.clear();
  do {
    groupPage = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'google.com',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: groupPageToken
    });
    var groups = groupPage.groups; //Gets the list of groups and begins to iterate for each one
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups[i];
        listArray.push([group.name]);
        var membersPageToken, membersPage;
        do {
          membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group.email, {
            maxReults: 100,
            pageToken: membersPageToken});
          var members = membersPage.members;
          if (members) {
            for (var u = 0; u < members.length; u++) {
              var member = members[u];
              listArray.push(member.email);
              outputSheet.getRange(u+1, i+1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);
            } 
        listArray = [];
      } membersPageToken = membersPage.nextPageToken;
    } while (membersPageToken);
   } 
  }
 } while (groupPageToken);
  try {
    outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allGroups');
    outputSheet.getDataRange();
  } catch(err) {
    outputSheet = ss.insertSheet('allGroups', 2);
  }
}
```

Expected results would be that a list of groups would populate across row 1, and the list of member's emails would appear below each group. Currently once I get to 
`outputSheet.getRange(u+1, i+1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);`
 it tells me that can't convert the Array to an Object and fails.

### EDIT

I've managed to get it working thanks to AMolina, Ross, and Cooper. This is the code I've got now:

```
function listAllGroupsAndMembers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var groupPageToken, groupPage;
  var listArray = [];
  var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allGroups') || ss.insertSheet('allGroups', 1);
  var p = 0;
  outputSheet.clear();
  do {
    groupPage = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'google.com',
      pageToken: groupPageToken
    });
    var groups = groupPage.groups; //Gets the list of groups and begins to iterate for each one
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups[i];
        listArray.push([group.name]);
        var membersPageToken, membersPage;
        do {
          membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group.email, {
            maxReults: 100,
            pageToken: membersPageToken});
          var members = membersPage.members;
          if (members) {
            for (var u = 0; u < members.length; u++) {
              var member = members[u];
              listArray.push([member.email]);
            } 
          if(membersPageToken != undefined) {
            p = p + 200;
          } else { p = 0; }
            Logger.log(p);
          outputSheet.getRange(p+1, i+1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);
          listArray = [];
          } membersPageToken = membersPage.nextPageToken;

        } while (membersPageToken);
      } 
    }
  } while (groupPageToken);
  try {
    outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allGroups');
    outputSheet.getDataRange();
  } catch(err) {
    outputSheet = ss.insertSheet('allGroups', 2);
  }
}
```

It also is able to handle when there's more than 200 members in a group.

Comment: Try `listArray.push([member.email]);`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked in getting the script to run. However, now it repeats the title of the group the same number of times as the members in the group. For groups larger than 200 members there seems to be some sort of issue where it repeats one member's email 200 times and then follows it with the last 200. I tried setting the getRange to be just u but that says the starting row of the range is too small.

Comment: Perhaps you might like something like this instead: `if (members) {
            for (var u = 0; u < members.length; u++) {
              var member = members[u];
              listArray.push([member.email]);
            } 
  outputSheet.getRange(1,1,listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);` getValues() and  setValues() is a very efficient way to handle data in Google  Apps Script because it handles data as a two dimensional array. This may require reworking your entire script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function listAllGroupsAndMembers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var groupPageToken, groupPage;
  var listArray = [];
  var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allGroups') || ss.insertSheet('allGroups', 1);
  outputSheet.clear();
  do {
    groupPage = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
      domain: 'sbtagent197.eu',
      maxResults: 100,
      pageToken: groupPageToken
    });
    var groups = groupPage.groups; //Gets the list of groups and begins to iterate for each one
    if (groups) {
      for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var group = groups[i];
        listArray.push([group.name]);
        var membersPageToken, membersPage;
        do {
          membersPage = AdminDirectory.Members.list(group.email, {
            maxReults: 100,
            pageToken: membersPageToken});
          var members = membersPage.members;
          if (members) {
            for (var u = 0; u < members.length; u++) {
              var member = members[u];
              listArray.push([member.email]);
            } 

            // This is where I made the change, moving this line outside the inner loop.
            outputSheet.getRange(1, i+1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);

            listArray = [];
          } membersPageToken = membersPage.nextPageToken;
        } while (membersPageToken);
      } 
    }
  } while (groupPageToken);
  try {
    outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('allGroups');
    outputSheet.getDataRange();
  } catch(err) {
    outputSheet = ss.insertSheet('allGroups', 2);
  }
}
```

I modified the code you had by changing the location of the `outputSheet.getRange(1, i+1, listArray.length, listArray[0].length).setValues(listArray);` line, you were calling it several times during the loop, which was causing the title to appear many times. basically, you were writing the block of `group_name -> members` over and over, one row lower every time, so it looked like you were writing the title a bunch of times when it was the whole thing.

The edited code sets the values once when the array is complete, it will write the name of the group in the first row and the members in the rows below it. Moving forward I would suggest you consider @Cooper 's advice, using [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) can make working with sheets much easier.